# azure notification hub send with templateHub

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-notificationhub

i cant find how to send a push using registered template name.

i am using this doc as reference.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530747.aspx

to recap my understanding.

1. i register my device with a tag AND a templatename.

   await hub.RegisterTemplateAsync(channelUri, template, templateName, tags);
2. then to send

   await hub.SendTemplateNotificationAsync(properties, tag);

Q1. how/what is the template name specified for the push?

any help appreciated.

-lp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single device may have several template registrations. In that case some name is required to maintain them on device. Device SDKs usually use it.

For sending purposes only tags are used. So template name does not really matter for the sending perspective.